# How to set audio device priority

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, speakers, kodi

I have problem with my audio devices in my computer. I have 3 audio devices: PC Speakers, Headphones, TV Output. I want to switch between them automatically by this rule: If the headphones are connected - use them for all pc tasks, Else, for Kodi and Steam games use TV Output and for all the other programs use PC Speakers.

Does anyone knows a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

*Sorry for the even later answer, following up on @RedBullNinja's good comments.*

Windows remembers default devices according to a timestamp representing to when they were marked as default.

Example 3 output devices: Speakers, headphones (3.5mm), and a Bluetooth headset.

You set your speakers as default 2 days ago, bluetooth headset yesterday, then finally 3.5mm headphones this morning. Whenever your 3.5mm headphones are connected (and enabled) that would get top dibs on preferred output, though once unplugged or disabled the bluetooth headset would now become the preferred output. If both the 3.5mm headphones and bluetooth headset are unplugged (or disabled) finally the speakers would be your output device.

Each time you click "Set Default" for a device the timestamp for that becomes most recent putting it at the top of the pile. You can therefore connect up all our possible output devices, enable them, then click "Set Default" for each one starting with your lowest preference to highest to define your exact order.

There are also two of theses lists: Once for regular audio, and again for communication audio. (You've probably already noticed the drop down caret on the default button to set default for just one type of audio there.)

What this doesn't answer is what happens with newly added devices never used before. I don't know if Windows would consider them to be the new top of the pile, and could be annoying for it to do so.

It's also annoying that you can't just see the current priority order without trawling through your system registry matching up somewhat random hardware IDs. (A small utility to see/manage that order would be very welcome!)

Comment: Any reference that windows remembers the default order according to the timestamp? or is this an observation by you?

Comment: Both. This is very easy to test yourself, but also source: https://ininet.org/default-audio-endpoint-selection-in-windows-7-march-30-2010.html (pages 2 and 3)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will check the link.

Comment: No problem. Microsoft have an API for reading/writing these endpoint timestamps too, but I didn't have that URL to hand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. Took me a while to figure this one out.

While there is no way to determine auto device priority in windows that I am aware of, as I simply wanted windows by default to switch between my headphones and my speakers, I did the following.

To achieve this I simply disabled all of the other audio devices connected to my system with the exception of my speakers. Plugged my headphones in, and set that to the default device, then when I disconnected my headphones, windows defaults to my speakers since there is no other option available.

Comment: Sorry for the even later answer, but Windows remembers default device priority with a timestamp according to when they were last marked as default. Example 3 outputs: speakers, headphones (3.5mm), and Bluetooth headset. -- You set your speakers default 2 days ago, bluetooth headset yesterday, and 3.5mm headphones this morning. - Whenever you plug in your 3.5mm headset that would get top dibs on preferred default output device, but once unplugged the bluetooth headset would get it. - Each time you click "Set Default" for a device the timestamp for that becomes most recent putting it at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the speaker icon in the taskbar, "Playback devices", "Set as default device".

Comment: He doesn't want to have to "Set as default device" every single time he turns on or off his headphones (much like myself).