# Windows 11 doesn't change audio output automatically

Tags: windows-11

So here's the problem: When I plug in headphones or connect bluetooth ones, each and every time I have to go to audio settings and change audio output manually. After disconnecting I have to repeat the same steps or there's no audio at all. I want the process to be automatic, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Sound settings window, you can set a Default audio device of each type:

1. Playback device
2. Communication device - usually used for phone/video audio like web meetings
3. Recording device

When the current audio device is disconnected, Windows reverts to your [most recently-selected default device](https://superuser.com/a/1482424/673426). From the description of your issue, it seems likely that either:

- You have an audio "device" which doesn't actually play audio (like an hdmi output for example), and windows is switching back to that instead. This could be fixed by disabling the device, or it should go away after manually switching to other devices a few times to put them at a higher "priority"
- Windows doesn't recognize that you've disconnected your device for some reason. This can happen if you connect your headphones/speakers into a dock, monitor, or some other external device that doesn't communicate its status very well.

Windows 11 also allows you to set default sound devices per-application in the [volume mixer section](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-sound-settings-windows-11), which can either add to the complexity, or be a better solution for you.

---

That's all assuming that the fault isn't in the software you're using rather than windows. Many applications like Webex/Teams allow you to set audio devices independently of windows, so it won't be of much help.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, laptop speakers weren't set as default. After setting it as default, the problem is solved